# Is there a way to separate route variable and route args in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Currently I have

```
@app.route("/api/job/<job_id>")
def handle_request(job_id):
  print(job_id)
```

While when the request url is '/api/job/456?id=123'

job_id becomes 456?id=123.
Is there a way I can get the job_id as 456 and exclude the args part?

Comment: Can you try: <int:job_id> or <int:job_id>/ with a trailing /

Answer (score 0):

Use [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) to get parsed contents of query string:

```
from flask import request

@app.route(...)
def handle_request():
    id = request.args.get('id')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting the id with no problem using 'id = request.args.get('id')'. I am just wondering if there is a easier way to locate the variable before the question mark which is 456 instead of getting the entire '456?id=123'